# How to print custom text in login page ? Magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer, login

This code checks whether the customer status is suspended, then the customer cannot log in and returns to the login page, but I need to print his status or any text after or before login form or everywhere in login page , can you help me?

```
namespace CustomerLogin\CheckStatus\Plugin;

use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\InvalidEmailOrPasswordException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\EmailNotConfirmedException;

class AccountManagement {
    /**
     * @var CustomerRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $customerRepository;

    public function __construct(
        CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
    )
    {
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
    }
    public function aroundAuthenticate(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement $subject,
        $proceed,
        $username,
        $password
    )
    {
        try {
            $customer = $this->customerRepository->get($username);
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            throw new InvalidEmailOrPasswordException(__('Invalid login or password.'));
        }

        $CustomerfieldValue= $customer->getCustomAttribute('customer_status')
            ? $customer->getCustomAttribute('customer_status')->getValue()
            :154;
        // Condition match throw error for prevent log
        if($CustomerfieldValue == 154)
        {
            throw new InvalidEmailOrPasswordException(__('Access is locked'));
            // access prevent
            // throw new EmailNotConfirmedException(__('Access is locked'));
        }
        // Call original Method

       return  $proceed($username,$password);


    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to restrict customer status is suspended while login?

Comment: i want to display text to the login page for example "Your status is inactive "

Comment: the rest is all done as i need